# In chrome version 57, the css position fixed is behaving odd when it has a parent container whose left is changing

Tags: css, google-chrome

When a child element with position fixed is present inside a container element with position relative and its left being changed in javascript, the child element moves with the container in chrome 57. The code below explains this behaviour.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    $('.container').animate({
      left: "-=10",
    })
  }, 10)
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.fix {
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 800px;
  top: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fix">
    Fixed
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But in firefox and chrome 56, the child element remains in the same place irrespective of the container element.

Is this a bug in the latest chrome ? Also checked the changelog for chrome 57 which didn't say anything about this.

Comment: Im currently using chrome 57 and i see the fixed box static :S

Comment: @Diego : Here's what I see
Chrome 57:
https://youtu.be/Vz0XGY6tvPI 

Firefox
https://youtu.be/a5RfIj5F6Bc

Comment: uh, curious behaviour... ill do some tests later, thanks for the info, im glad you shared and resolved it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not override the top and left of a fixed element, they are defined by the webkit rendering engine as the top and left of their  relative parent.In this case the changing left. Try adding a position left, right,  bottom or top to your fixed element.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    $('.container').animate({
      left: "-=10",
    })
  }, 10)
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.fix {
  left:0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 800px;
  top: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fix">
    Fixed
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: We can't give a value to our child element like you have suggested, just wanted to know whether this behaviour in the latest chrome is here to stay or to be retracted ? Also this behaviour is different from the spec, whereas in firefox this works out as expected.

Comment: It is not an issue in a particular version of chrome, I'm using version 55 and still have this issue. In a sense it is not an issue but how webkit layout engine renders fixed element without any specified top/right/bottom/left values. So you'll find this happening in most chrome versions and Safari as well as they share the same layout engine.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I was trying out my application on Chrome 57 and the behaviour seemed to have changed. I was speculating that the position was an issue but that seems to be only a part of the problem.